# How do you create evenly spaced coordinates for a given number of points to be set in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, simulation

Given an input of 'n' points, how do you create a set of coordinates that represent these points evenly distributed (approximately) inside a two dimensional area (eg. 1m x 1m).

For context:

```
n = 12 ## number of particles in simulation
separation <- 1/(1+ids) ## Separation distance. Set according to the number of particles and size of box (1m x 1m)
frame_total <- 200 ## number of frames in simulation
df <- expand.grid(frame = 1:frame_total, id = 1:n) ## constructs data frame based on the number of points 
df_length <- nrow(df) 
df$x_pos <- runif(df_length) ## initializing vector of equal length to 'df' for x position
df$y_pos <- runif(df_length) ## initializing vector of equal length to 'df' for y position
```

I'd like to initialize the position of 'n' particles, before a physics simulation begins. The particles can't start too close to one another. The set of coordinates that represent these initial positions will then go into 'df' as the first frame for each individual particle.

This was my first attempt which works to an extent. Once 'n' becomes too large however, this method breaks down.

```
## sets the initial x position, evenly spaced across the box
df$x_pos <- if_else(df$frame == 1, (df$id)*spr, df$x_pos)

## sets the initial y position, evenly spaced across the box
df$y_pos <- if_else(df$frame == 1, (df$id)*spr, df$x_pos)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `runif()` function might place points too close together. You might look into poisson disc sampling, for example in https://github.com/coolbutuseless/poissoned or https://github.com/will-r-chase/poissondisc or pracma::poisson2disk.

Comment: Maybe the `particles` package could be used here. See my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/605436/214015

Comment: Position the points "exactly" in a grid.  The perturb them randomly, with the degree of perturbation chosen to make sure the points don't swap positions. Repeat for each simulation.

Comment: @jblood94 I checked out your response in the linked question and it looks great. I tried to start a chat to discuss but I hit an error. Would the particles package be a good way to animate a system of interacting particles that have a repulsive and attractive force on one another, dependent on distance? I managed to reproduce your plots, but couldn't work out how to animate the process.

Comment: Yes, it should handle that. If you plan to use it extensively, I would recommend viewing the introduction and referring to the documentation. The linked answer is the first time I looked at the package, and it only took a couple hours to figure out. For animation, the only way I can see is to `evolve` in increments to make images to stitch together.

Comment: Thanks @jblood94. I've been going through the documentation and I've come across the fact that the particle mass and time step between increments are both set to 1. I can't see a way to change these, so I think I'll have to write the loops from scratch. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up going with:

```
n <- 10 ## number of particles
m <- ceiling(sqrt(n))  ## number of rows or columns in the grid

## create a grid of x and y coordinates
grid_init <- expand.grid(x = seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.8/m), y = seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.8/m))

## sample n coordinates from the grid
coords <- grid_init[sample(nrow(grid_init), n), ]

## plot the coordinates
ggplot2::ggplot(coords, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of "tricks" to create special distributions.  Some of them are bizarre, involving transforms.   In your case, since you only care about keeping the initial positions "not too close together," a couple simple methods could be used.

1. Create a grid within your space.  Then randomly place a point inside each cell, but away from the walls, e.g., for a square cell with coordinates zero and one,  set  `Px <- runif(1, 0.01, 0.99)` and same for `Py`  .
2. Generate a nice big set of coordinates such as

   ```
   AllX <- runif(1e4, xmin,xmax)
   AllY <- runif(1e4, ymin, ymax)      # next,get all distances
   distMat <- dist(rbind(AllX,AllY))
   ```

Then just find all the points for which corresponding `distMat` values are too small and throw them away.

I do like  the suggestions in the comments to use  `particles` library functions.  Depends a bit on whether you want to stick with `base` R or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response Carl. The particles package seems to suit my application nicely, but I'll keep your solution in mind.